# Samson Stage XPD1 USB wireless microphone interference problems

Tags: microphone, wireless

I am using a [Samson - Stage XPD1](http://www.samsontech.com/samson/products/wireless-systems/stage-series/stagexpd1/) USB wireless microphone connected to a laptop and am trying to get it to project my voice through the laptop, however when I click listen to this device in the settings I am getting a lot of interference through the speakers.

I have fiddled with the gain and different frequencies but the interference remains pretty much the same, the sound when I am speaking into the microphone is fine its just the interference in the background is very annoying.

It remains the same whether the laptop is plugged in or not.

Any ideas how to get rid of this?

Many thanks in advance

Ryan

Comment: What kind of 'interference'?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Told it's like a whistling sound. Is there anyway I can upload it on here as I've recorded it?

Comment: Are you getting feeback?  A whistling sound sounds a bit like feedback.

Comment: Not sure if it's feedback or interference to be honest. Tried a USB extension cable and doesn't make any difference unfortunately :( is there anyway to upload the sound onto this site so you can hear it?

Comment: @user17200 - we have soundcloud integration if you upload it to soundcloud and link to the audio there.

Answer (score -1):

What about using a USB extension cable to move the receiver further away from the computer?  Computers can greatly interfere with wireless signals.